# await context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download(f'./R{p}.txt') AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'download'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-telegram-bot

I want to save a file in txt format in my system, but I get an error

```
async def Getfile(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    global p, usres
    await context.bot.get_file(await update.message.document).download(f'./R{p}.txt')
    await update.message.reply_text(f"file saved as R{p}.txt")
    usres[int(update.message.from_user.id)] = p
    with open("data.json", "w") as file:
        json.dump(usres, file, indent=4)
    p += 1
    print("ok")
```

> Error :    await
> context.bot.get_file(update.message.document).download(f'./R{p}.txt')
> AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'download'

**Version used**

1. python == 3.8
2. python-telegram-bot==20.0a1

Comment: Just a guess, but does `(await context.bot.get_file(...)).download(...)` work? (note the additional brackets)

Comment: `await(await context.bot.get_file(update.message.document)).download(f'./R{p}.txt')`
this works for me thanks  Please post in as Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that `context.bot.get_file(update.message.document)` returns a coroutine that needs to be awaited first, so try:

```
await (await context.bot.get_file(await update.message.document)).download(f'./R{p}.txt')
```